# SVN Serve, Missing a Directory

Tags: svn

I'm sure this is an asinine question, and I blame myself for not fully understanding how the SVNSERVE process works.

I have an SVN repo, but it needs to be moved to a server within a clients cloud.  I did this a while back and ran into the issue of the SVNSERVE.exe process not getting set to the right directory.

I have the SVNSERVE.exe process running as a windows service and pointing to the right directory.  There are two other repos there that are serving out fine in the same directory.  I copied out the new directory just like I did with the others, but I'm getting the error "No repository found".  I thought that SVNSERVE just looked at that directory and served out the repositories that were there, but I have had a hard time finding more information about that.

I thought it was a Windows permission problem, but I set the whole folder to be full control to EVERYONE, so that's not it.

I feel horrible I didn't fully understand this problem the first time I fought it, but it's late on a Sunday night and clients are yelling.  Anyone know what I'm missing?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

It's specific to the repository.  I tested the same process with some of the other repos we have on our server and when I copied them up, they worked just as expected.

This bug is breaking me and I wish I could provide more details, but that's all I know.  I'm going to try to do an SVN Dump instead of an XCopy and see how that goes.  I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If the url of the repo the clients use has changed the clients with need to do an `svn switch --relocate`

But it sounds like youre having server issues.  Don`t really have enough info to help you.

Comment: It's a repo that was on our server and I copied it up to their server.

They don't need to do anything on the client side since they never had the repo.

Answer (score 0):

We need more info.

What does this report:

> svnadmin verify path/to/repository

And can you do a checkout locally on the server?